# Can't google translate response-data from Axios to English - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, axios, google-translate

I am trying to convert the data from an axios response to English. I made a component called Translator. I tried to use the component but seems like it doesn't work. So I want to find a way to integrate Google Translate API with my project, but I am still confused and don't know how to do it.

Translator.tsx:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

interface PropsType {
  text: string,
  language?: string
}

const Translator: React.FC<PropsType> = ({ text, language = "en" }) => {
  const [convertedText, setConvertedText] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    const response = axios
      .post(
        'https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2',
        {},
        {
          params: {
            q: text,
            target: language,
            key: 'API_KEY'
          }
        }
      )
      .then((response) => {
        setConvertedText(response.data.data.translations[0].translatedText);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log('rest api error', err);
      });
  }, [text, language]);

  return <>
    {convertedText}
    </>;
};

export default Translator;
```

I wanted to translate the "data" into English, but it seems like I can't do it with Translator component.
[image]

The response data from the axios is:

[image]